# KDB Discrete Select Multiple items

Tags: select, kdb

From a FIX schema I have a column called channelID. The channelID column can have a value of SERVERNAME-Inbound, SERVERNAME-Client, SERVERNAME-Venue.

Currently trying to do an efficient select by selecting the first 10,000 rows via:

```
'time xdesc select [2500] from table_name where (channelID like "*Inbound)
```

This works well and retrieves the first 2,500 rows where channelID has Inbound.

I would like to effectively run a query where I am selecting the first 2500 instances where the channel ID has "Inbound", "Client", or "Venue".

The only thought process I have here is to do a self join on the table. The resultant set should be 7,500 rows where it is 2,500 of each channelID ("Inbound", "Client", or "Venue").

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for is something like:

```
select from table_name where any channelId like/: ("*Inbound";"*Client";"*Venue"), 2499 >= (iasc;i) fby channelID
```

The first part of the where clause will filter the table down to only those rows where channelID is in the IDs you're looking for.
The second part will take that subtable and use `fby` to return where the indices within the set of each remaining channelID are less than or equal to 2499 (due to indexing starting from 0).